# Hibernate: Could not update objectName

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, soap

can you enumerate reasons why I cant save/update this entity in my Hibernate project:

error goes like:

```
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not update: [org.game.model.heroChampion#123456]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2360)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2242)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:92)
```

and

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not update: [org.game.model.heroChampion#123456]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:634)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:695)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:566)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:510)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:310)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
```

This object is part of many-to-one relationship in DB.
just enumerate possible reasons and I'll check my code.

things I tried.

```
  public void saveHeroChampion(final HeroChampion hero) {


        getHibernateTemplate().clear();

        getHibernateTemplate().refresh(hero);
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(sputumSmear); 
        getHibernateTemplate().flush();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `clear` it removes the instance of `hero` from the session cache so the object is detached and no longer persisted. Try removing that line.